Stars and bars, with constraints for each $x_i$
I have been working on the following problem:
How many integer solutions are there to the equation:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=11$$
where each $x_i$ satisfies the constraint $0 ≤ x_i ≤ 3$ for each $i$.
I found the answer to be number of solutions = $4$, since the only way to get a result $= 11$ would be by adding $3+3+3+2$, meaning there must be three $3$s and one $2$ added together in any order.
However, I am curious to know of a better way of approaching such a problem.
I know that the stars and bars method can be used to count the number of non-negative integer solutions without constraints, but I'm unsure how to apply inclusion-exclusion to account for the upper limit of $3$ on each $x_i$​. Could someone walk me through the steps to apply inclusion-exclusion to this problem and calculate the number of valid solutions?

The general constrained problem is somewhat messy.    As you say, your particular example isn't very hard.

You can use stars and bars for this problem, avoiding inclusion-exclusion by a slight twist.
First fill all the bins with the maximum permissible $3$, giving a total of $12$
Now instead of putting  balls into bins, apply stars and bars taking out balls from bins, to get
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1,\;\; x_i \geq 0$ to get
$$\binom{1+4-1}{4-1} = \binom43 = 4$$
This twist can profitably be used in many (but not all) such problems to either eliminate inclusion-exclusion altogether, or reduce it to a shorter version.
